# How to add web server in farm in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, load-balancing

We have SharePoint 2013 Farm - 3 Web server + 2 app server + 1 DB server. Setup NLB cluster from Web servers.

One of web servers is working bad in latest time.

Can I do add new web server in farm and add in NLB cluster and later delete old server from NLB and farm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the New WFE into the SharePoint farm and add into the NLB cluster anytime. You have to make sure couple of things.

- SharePoint version should be same on new server ( same cu level)
- set the permission on the server i.e. farm admin account
- apply / make custom changes on the server i.e. web.config change and any other settings
- Update the IIS bindings and SSL certs ( if any)
- Update the NLB cluster
- Make sure all the required service running on the server which
- Now test the server.

To remove the server from the farm, you can do it any time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that.
Also, you can delete the bad server firstly, then add the new one. They are both OK.